# Should there be a restriction on account renames?

Tags: discussion, users, abuse

Should there be some form of restriction on the number of times an account can be renamed?  If so what?

Comment: Is this because of my little joke this week here in meta?

Comment: me being `spam`, AKA `eggs spam ham and spam`, AKA `smeagol` AKA `Tom Bombadil` (for 5 minutes), AKA `voyager AKA spam and spam`

Comment: damn, it seemed more sensible back when the `spam` joke where born...

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the restriction should be on the frequency - e.g. only allow one rename per week (or month), or only allow a rename after a certain rep score is reached.

There may be perfectly valid reasons why someone wants to rename their account. Of course there might not be, but you can't punish everyone for what a few people do.

Comment: +1 I had some form of frequency in mind as well

Answer (score 3):

What problem is a lack of restriction causing/allowing?

Answer (score 2):

> Should there be some form of restriction on the number of times an account can be renamed?

Yes.

> If so what?

37,159 times. And not one time more.

Comment: Interesting... I would have selected 65535 myself

Comment: That would be ridiculous. Imagine, renaming your account that many times... i swear, programmers and their magic numbers!

Comment: I happen to like magic! Specifically when it is associated with numbers and the like

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see the need, since everything in the system is tied to user id (a unique number), and based on that id your profile, stats, recent activity, etc. are persistent and visible to everyone who cares to look.

The only possible reason to restrict it would be if there were some form of abuse taking place.  Given that, I am having a hard time imagining what kind of abuse could take place that wouldn't be more easily handled by moderator intervention, rather than by implementing a name change limit.